# What is continuation of solutions to Picard's Existence and uniqueness of ODEs theorem

Tags: differential-equations

Picard's Existence and uniqueness theorem proves existence of solutions to an ODE on a a particular interval, but then I believe there exists some kind of theorem that allows us to continue the solution past that interval.

Is this true? Where can I find it's proof? or can someone explain it to me?

Comment: This question may be better suited to http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Here's the short version: repeat the argument with the old final time the new initial time.  If the function is Lipschitz, the intervals are all the same length and you get global existence and uniqueness.  If the function is only locally Lipschitz, the length of the intervals could shrink so quickly that the solution blows up in finite time.

Comment: Any chance of seeing how to proof works formally?